# Which Unicode encoding does the Linux kernel use?

Tags: linux, unicode, character-encoding

I have learned that Windows uses UTF-16LE on x86/x64 systems.  What about Linux?  Which Unicode encoding does it use: UTF-16LE or UTF-32?

Comment: What makes you think Linux favors any particular encoding?  Are you asking whether common Linux distributions assume that configuration files are encoded using a particular encoding or whether syscalls assume that inputs are strings of code-points encoded using a particular encoding?

Comment: Why do you mention the processor architecture?  Are you under the impression that the architecture for which you compile Linux affects the encoding beyond endianness?

Comment: @Mike Samuel: I am asking which encoding do syscalls assume?

Comment: Somewhat related to [Why is it that UTF-8 encdoing is used when interacting with a Unix or Linux Environment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164430/why-is-it-that-utf-8-encoding-is-used-when-interacting-with-a-unix-linux-environ/).

Comment: [UTF-32](http://www.unicode.org/faq//utf_bom.html) comes in BE and LE forms too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.xsquawkbox.net/xpsdk/mediawiki/Unicode says

> #### Linux
>
> On Linux, UTF8 is the 'native' encoding for all strings, and is the format accepted by system routines like `fopen()`.

so Linux is like [Plan 9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plan_9_from_Bell_Labs#Unicode) in that respect, and [boost::filesystem and Unicode under Linux and Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307033/boostfilesystem-and-unicode-under-linux-and-windows) notes

> It looks to me like `boost::filesystem` under Linux does not provide a wide character string in `path::native()`, despite `boost::filesystem::path` having been initialized with a wide string.

which would rule out UTF-16 and UTF-32 since all variants of those require wide character support -- NUL bytes allowed inside strings.

Comment: I thought Linux only sees paths as bytes, not as UTF-8 characters.

Comment: @melab, [lwn](https://lwn.net/Articles/71472/) tends to agree that the kernel is charset-agnostic and treats paths as nul-terminated byte arrays.  One ignores userspace conventions at one's peril though.

Answer (score 3):

Generally Unix prefers UTF-8.  This [document](ftp://ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/docs/lanana/unicode/unicode.txt) suggests that Linux kernel does too.